# What is wrong on this Decimal.TryParse?

Tags: c#, tryparse

Code :

```
Decimal kilometro = Decimal.TryParse(myRow[0].ToString(), out decimal 0);
```

some arguments are not valid?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`out decimal 0`  is not a valid parameter - `0` is not a valid variable name.

```
decimal output;
kilometro = decimal.TryParse(myRow[0].ToString(), out output);
```

By the way, the return value will be a `bool` - from the name of the variable, your code should probably be:

```
if(decimal.TryParse(myRow[0].ToString(), out kilometro))
{ 
  // success - can use kilometro
}
```

Since you want to return `kilometro`, you can do:

```
decimal kilometro = 0.0; // Not strictly required, as the default value is 0.0
decimal.TryParse(myRow[0].ToString(), out kilometro);

return kilometro;
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess that `kilometro` is also a `double`, instead of the required `bool` return type indicating success.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the `decimal.TryParse` returns a `bool` type - so you need to do something like:

```
Decimal kilometro;

// if .TryParse is successful - you'll have the value in "kilometro"
if (!Decimal.TryParse(myRow[0].ToString(), out kilometro)
{ 
   // if .TryParse fails - set the value for "kilometro" to 0.0
   kilometro = 0.0m;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage of the TryParse statement is given below.
You must declare the decimal first and then pass it into the TryParse method. If the TryParse succeeds, `kilometro` will be the new value, otherwise it will be zero. I believe that was your desired outcome.

```
decimal kilometro = 0;
if (Decimal.TryParse(myRow[0].ToString(), out kilometro))
{
   //The row contained a decimal.
}
else {
   //The row could not be parsed as a decimal.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as an additional answer, you can now declare out parameters inline.

```
if (decimal.TryParse(myRow[0].ToString(), out decimal outParamName))
{
    // do stuff with decimal outParamName
}
```